# Add a comma at the end of every line

Tags: bash, sed

I need to format a mailing list, by adding a comma at the end of every line. This question has been already asked, however I don't get the expected result with the suggested answer:

```
sed '$!s/$/,/' file > out.txt
```

results in:

```
user1@gmail.com
,
user2@gmail.com
,
user3@yahoo.fr
. . .
```

Is there anyway it can be improved ?
I'd need rather need:

```
user1@gmail.com,
user2@gmail.com,
user3@yahoo.fr,
. . .
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the following approach to add comma at the end of each line:

```
sed 's/$/,/' file > out.txt
```

> s/regexp/replacement/flags

Comment: The `g` flag isn't necessary; that applies the substitution to every match (not just the first match) in a single line, but by definition any line will only match `$` exactly once. The thing that made the difference here was dropping the `$!` selector, which matches all but the last line.

Comment: when i did this it added ',' to the end of every line. EXCEPT the first line, it replaced the first character with ',' instead....   [UPDATE] turns out that's what happens when you unix2dos your csv file before running that.